# How to customize zii cgrid coiumn which are not in my database

Tags: yii

I am using zii.widgets.grid.CGridView.....i want to add new coulmn in this.which is not in my database.how to add this column so that it show in listing

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new column and stablish the value by hand:

```
'columns'=>array(
    'something',
    array(              
        'header'=> 'Custom',
        'type'  => 'raw',
        'value' => '"something"'
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

These two articles may help:

CGridView reference:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

CGridView - render custom columns:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/278/cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns/